# Is there a programatic way to half a CIDR block in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, cidr

I have a CIDR block, and I would like to exactly half it, so that I have two ranges that I can use within my Terraform project.

e.g. `10.10.10.0/24`, which includes IPs in range 10.10.10.0 - 10.10.10.255
can be split to `10.10.10.0/25` & `10.10.10.128/25`

I've tried looking at this with [cidrsubnet function](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/cidrsubnet), but I don't really understand how to use it to get from the first range to the second range.

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with [`cidrsubnet`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/cidrsubnet) as you pointed out.

```
output "first_half" {
  value = cidrsubnet("10.10.10.0/24", 1, 0) # 10.10.10.0/25
}

output "second_half" {
  value = cidrsubnet("10.10.10.0/24", 1, 1) # 10.10.10.128/25
}
```

Explenation:

`cidrsubnet` takes 3 arguments: `cidrsubnet(prefix, newbits, netnum)`.

- The `prefix` is the actual CIDR range you want to cut in half.
- `newbits` is the number of additional bits which you want to extend the prefix. For example, if you have `/24` prefix and you want to have `/25` prefixes, `newbits` is the difference between 25 and 24: `25 - 24 = 1`
- `netnum` is a whole number which is no more than `newbits` binary digits. In our case it can be either `0` or `1`. `0` will be the range of `10.10.10.0/25`, while `1` will represent the second half, being `10.10.10.128/25`.

To give you another example, which makes it more understandable, lets cut `10.10.10.0/24` if 4 ranges:

We know, that we need `/26` ranges, so `26 - 24 = 2` for the `newbits`. For `netnum`, we can have 0, 1, 2, 3, for which in the binary digits are `00`, `01`, `10`, `11`.

```
cidrsubnet("10.10.10.0/24", 2, 0) # 10.10.10.0/26
cidrsubnet("10.10.10.0/24", 2, 1) # 10.10.10.64/26
cidrsubnet("10.10.10.0/24", 2, 2) # 10.10.10.128/26
cidrsubnet("10.10.10.0/24", 2, 3) # 10.10.10.192/26
```

Comment: Thank you - this explanation really cleared up how to use `cidrsubnet1 effectively.